# How to disable same origin policy for chrome new tab?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, userscripts, tampermonkey

I'd like a user-script to increase the zoom size of the tiles in the default chrome new tab. I used to be able to access them directly but recently (in the last year or so) they've changed the new tab to use an iframe for the tiles. I never got around to fixing it, until recently I am trying again.

So I can't change it any more — with code like `jQ('#mv-single').contents().find('.mv-tile').css("zoom", 1.4);` I get no results, and using jQuery at the console shows me the reason:

```
jQ('#mv-single').contents().find("body")
VM8405:8 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.google.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.(…)
```

The iframe itself is:

```
<iframe id="mv-single" src="chrome-search://most-visited/single.html?removeTooltip=No%20mostrar%20en%20esta%20p%C3%A1gina"></iframe>
```

A **bad** alternative that I'm not interested in is disabling web security. I don't want to permanently and globally turn off all web security, it seems like a bad idea (and is only mentioned as a general solution for developers who are debugging their code). But turning it off just for this page would be great. :)

An alternative would be to write a custom new tab page, but this doesn't look entirely easy for me. There are things I like about the new tab page — the google account bar at the top, the *trending* pages from my recent history in tiles.. the only part I don't really need is the search bar in the middle.

It would definitely be better if I could just change the CSS still. Any ideas?

Here is my current script (with most recent css changes from Elements view in console in the comments):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Chrome newtab
// @namespace    http://your.homepage/
// @version      1.0
// @description  css reformatting
// @author       You
// @include      /https?://www.google.com/_/chrome/newtab/
// @require      https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

window.jQ=jQuery.noConflict(true);

jQ(document).ready(function(){
    jQ('#mv-single').load(function(){
        jQ('#mv-single').contents().find('.mv-tile').css("zoom", 1.4);
        //  #mv-single {
        //     width: 80vw;
        //     margin-left: 10vw;
        //     margin-right: 10vw;
        //     height: 35vw;
        //  }
        //  #mv-single body { zoom: 165% }
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible with a userscript.  It may not even be possible with an extension.  Search for Chrome-extension questions about `chrome`* schemes.

Comment: @BrockAdams — there is an extension called "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *" that works across all web pages. I guess just refining this extension to allow it to be configured to only work on the new tab page would do. I don't really write extensions though ...

Comment: There is/was a global preference to disable same origin.  If that extension just sets that preference, then it still can't be made to do what you want.  But, look at the extension's code and see how it works.

Comment: this extension actually mentions that command line argument/ flag setting, but it says it does not do that. instead it injects a header into all http responses. I think that I need that, but restricted to just the new tab page.